# Why do I get a role provider related exception loading from the Content folder in my MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just deployed an MVC4 app to my hosting provider. I find my CSS is not rendering when I load the site, and when I try direct navigation to the CSS uri, I get an exception loading my role provider:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Educ8.Mvc' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> type="Educ8.Mvc.Core.Security.Educ8RoleProvider, Educ8.Mvc"

Yet when I access an action on an authorized controller, I get no such error. What could cause this, and why is any authorization being applied at all to the Content folder?

It seems that when I try and access a *Content* resource, a 'sub' application is started for the request in another folder lacking the bin folder of the main application, and the exception is thrown.

I note that files do load correctly from the *Scripts* folder though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be many reasons why you get such error, I will try to get an idea how to identify your:

1. try to set

   ```
   <location path="~/Content">
           <system.web>
                   <authentication mode="None" />
           </system.web>
   </location>
   ```
2. Put test value into application state from your code in controller or application start in globasl.asax

   ```
   HttpContext.Application["test"] = "test value";
   ```

   and get it from simple .aspx file in your Content folder with content:

   ```
   <%=HttpContext.Application["test"]%>
   ```
3. Try to skip all modules being run throw all requests

   ```
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
   </modules>
   ```
4. Disable minification and bundling feature of MVC 4

Comment: Thank you sir. No. 1 did it. I did think of that before, but forgot and got stuck wondering why the hell I would have to.